# NetBeans - How to hint the IDE about file type?

Tags: netbeans, mime-types, code-formatting

For example, I have an JavaScript file, but for certain reasons I can not add `.js` extension at the end of the filename, it is just `bin/mytool`. Is it possible to hint the NetBeans IDE that it is JavaScript file? Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/* @MIME-type: application/javascript */
var env = process.env;
```

Or maybe hint in separate file `.mimerc`:

```
bin/mytool application/javascript
```

If this feature is not supported natively maybe there is some plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin that does exactly what you want: https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-noext-mime-resolver. It is available, as well, in the list of Available Plugins of the IDE as *nb-noext-mime-resolver*.

Comment: Wooohooo! Thank you very much! It works, through required to upgrade Netbeans 8.0.2 to 8.1. Authors of Netbeans should make this plugin native.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. There is a version of the plugin for Netbeans 8.0 available in http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55076/no-extension-mime-resolver. I haven't tested though.